# skip dynamically generated min js files in TFS check-in

Tags: javascript, tfs, web-essentials, minifilter

I have a webessentials task that generates min.js files on every project build via the build task. However this builds and generates the new files that are not changed either, which shows up as more files during TFS check-in. Since these files are required for deployment, i cannot exclude them from the project.

Adding the .tfignore for the following also does not help.

```
*.min.js
..\*.min.js
```

Is there something wrong here or why does TFS ignore the .tfignore files after the min.js files are checked-in.

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce this issue, and there are some similar issues discussed in GitHub, eg : https://github.com/aspnet/Home/issues/962

As a workaround, before check in files, you can try to **Undo All** first, then copy the `.tfignore` file to the root folder which generated the `*.min.js` files, then manually **Add items to folder**, you will find that the `*.min.js` files are excluded this time, then check in the needed files.

1. Before check in:  **Pending Changes** > **Action** > **Undo All**
2. Navigate to workspace (Project local path), Create a `.tfignore` file with the exclusion rules and copy it to the root folder which generated the `*.min.js` files.
3. Check in the `.tfignore` file first. (Detected link > select the
   `.tfignore` file  > Promote  > check in )
4. Right click in **Source Control Explorer** > **Add items to folder** >
   Select the project folder > you will find that the `*.min.js` files
   are Excluded automatically, Click **Finish**  > **Check in** the changes.

Comment: @Saran Have you resolved the issue by above workaround? any update?